# Reading XML file from BLOB in java

Tags: java, xml, blob

I need to read a xml in zipped blob. Using sql developer, traditionally, I save the blob as .zip and then unzip it to view the xml file. But I need to automate this process using java. How should I proceed to read the XML using dom parser once blob is fetched from the DB ?

Comment: Requirement is to read the xml file kept inside the blob coming from DB. Once I get it as String, I can use DOM to read its node. Issue is that I am not able to find way to unzip the blob.

Answer (score 0):

There is a java tutorial on reading XML data into a DOM you can find it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html)

Comment: I know how to read a xml using dom parser. When I fetch blob column from DB, its in zipped format and xml file is inside it. Some code is required to extract the xml from the blob. Once I am able to reach till XML, reading should not be a problem.

Comment: How did you zip it?  There is a `java.util.zip.*` that will help you unzip.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html

Comment: Thanks Jayfray. Some external system is pushing the xml into a webservice which zip it and insert it as a blob into DB. I have no idea how this is zipped but now there is an urgency to read xml of all records and create a report. Currently we are manually downloading blob, unzipping it, opening xml and copying node value.

Comment: Well if it is a standard zip then the [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) should help

Comment: If you use the `ZipInputStream` you might be able to pipe that right into the DOM parser